# How can I get information about the audio file that was selected by the user? (using SAF and MediaStore)

Tags: java, android, mediastore, storage-access-framework

I can’t understand how to request data about a file (that was selected by the user) from [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore).

1) I open file picker like this

```
public static void launchPicker(Fragment f) {
        Intent pickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        pickerIntent.setType("audio/mpeg");
        pickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
        pickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        f.startActivityForResult(pickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

2) get the data from the intent

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data != null) {
            //multiselection only
            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
            if (clipData != null) {
                List<Uri> results = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    Uri uri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    if (uri != null) {
                        results.add(uri);
                    }
                }
                //TODO process result
            }
        }
    }
```

3) Now I have my list of DocumentUris. What should be my next step?

MediaSoter can convert mediaUri to documentUri via [Mediastore.getDocumentUri()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#getDocumentUri(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)), but I couldn't find a way to convert documentUri to mediaUri.

I would like to get these fields from MediaStore: [MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID), [ALBUM_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.html#ALBUM_ID), [ARTIST_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.html#ARTIST_ID).

Comment: The user-selected content may not be in `MediaStore`. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` can be handled by any app. You will need to treat this no differently than a URL to a Web-based piece of content: open a stream on the content and parse it using some MP3 metadata parser.

Comment: @CommonsWare I found [MediaExtractor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor) and it looks like it works, 
but I would like to add the selected files to [playlists](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Playlists). that’s why I want to get info from MediaStore.

Comment: Then use `ACTION_PICK` with a suitable `MediaStore` `Uri` in the `Intent`, so you limit yourself to media already known to the `MediaStore`.

Answer (score 0):

I do that this way:

```
Uri documentUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(mUri,
                    documentId);
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mContext,documentUri);
String albumName = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM); 
String album = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
String title = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
String artist = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
String track = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_CD_TRACK_NUMBER);
String duration = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
String year = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_YEAR);
```